# Sql table store edit history

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am working on a project using sql server database for storing data. I have a table:

**Record**

```
  Id                   - (PK)
  RecordTitle          - (varchar(400))
  IsDeleted            - (bit)
  LastUpdatedAtUtc     - (long - unix timestamp)
  LastUpdatedById      - (FK to UserTable)
```

*User can Add/Edit/Delete multiple records. So the relationship between UserTable and RecordTable is 1 to many*

I want to store Edit/Delete history of record in the same table. So if record is deleted we just set *IsDelete* column value *True*.

Similarly I want to store Edit history in the same table. So that whenever user edit any record the original record will not get changed instead a new record is inserted with the changes.

I want to know what should be the efficient way to handle this. Do we need to add new columns  in the record table to store edit history. If yes, then what are those columns?

Comment: Do you want to store such data in the same table? I think it's easier (and faster for queries) to use another _XyzHistory_ table with information you need (timestamp, author, modified record ID, modified column, new value and old value). If you do it in same table you may add a new record, copy of original unmodified one: you'll need an extra column _OriginalRecordId_ (to keep reference to original one), _IsHistory_ (to know it's an history record) and optionally a timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways.

1) Take a column ParentId and whenever any user edit the record, insert new record with ParentId with old record Id. So you will have all history.

2) Take another table named history table and save old record in that table and do update in original table. Don't forget to mention original table's id as one separate column.

3) You can take one column as history_column where you can save a string of what is changed from OLD to NEW.

Answer (score 1):

You could add new columns `version` & `record_group_id`.

1. when adding new record, the `version` will be `0`. `record_group_id` will be also be unique in this table.
2. when editing record, the `version` will increase by one, but it has the same `record_group_id` as previous one.
3. when deleting record, simply set the latest one's `IsDeleted` to `True`.

So, when finding the record, you could use the combination of `version` and `record_group_id` to load the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

Add a field called ParentRowId to the table and make a 1 to 1 relationship on the same table, this column contain the id of the old edited record and the new one contain the new values.