# Correctly Storing Record Edit History

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a database that with store employee records with their basic information (first name, surname, address etc.). However I want to be able to store a record of who last edited it including previous versions.

I was thinking of using a `version` and `version_group_id` where every time the record was edit it would create a new record with the `version` number increment going up each time and the `version_group_id` being the same as explained in this question:
[Sql table store edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355704/sql-table-store-edit-history)

However this database may be updated multiple times which would mean multiple records of the same person and this database may contain thousands of records and I wondered if this was the best practice?

Any other information would be very useful.

Comment: This is certainly possible. You can always update the version by using `version = version+1`. To make accurate and reliable recording of who edited the table. You would have to build a function which executes the query along with data of when and who is currently executing it. Then you can update this data to the database. For instance a mysqli_query could look something like this. `"UPDATE records SET name='John Doen', address='Testavenue', version = version+1, version_editor='$currently_logged_in_user' WHERE record_id = '$id'"`

Comment: As for performance or practice this isn't an issue. Just make sure you have the right database type to perform all the `UPDATE` statements. Some database types lock the whole table after a single update and only release it after the mysql connection has been broken. I think InnoDB releases the table after every query so a lot of Updates are possible.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I didn't want my table to cause issues later down the line through getting bogged down.